# Existence of stochastic matrices satisfying an equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to show that for any matrix $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\beta \in [0,1)$, there exist $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and stochastic $n{\times}n$-matrices $A$ and $B$ such that
$$ C = \alpha (A-B) (I- \beta A)^{-1}.$$

Note that it is important that $\beta < 1$ as otherwise the inverse of $I- \beta A$ does not exist.

Comment: this implies that $C\mathbf 1 =\mathbf 0$ and so cannot be true, e.g. if $C\in GL_n(\mathbb R)$

Comment: @user8675309 Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

being stochastic, $A,B$ each have the ones vector $\mathbf 1$ as a (right) eigenvector.  Thus
$(I- \beta A)\mathbf 1= (1-\beta)\mathbf 1\implies (I- \beta A)^{-1}\mathbf 1
=(1-\beta)^{-1}\mathbf 1$

Thus
$C\mathbf 1 = \alpha (A-B) (I- \beta A)^{-1}\mathbf 1=\alpha (1-\beta)^{-1}(A-B)\mathbf 1 = \alpha (1-\beta)^{-1}\mathbf 0=\mathbf 0$

so the conjecture that

> for any matrix $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\beta \in [0,1)$,
> there exist $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and stochastic
> $n{\times}n$-matrices $A$ and $B$ such that  $$ C = \alpha (A-B) (I-\beta A)^{-1}.$$

can't possibly be true

Comment: Thank you. Do you think that the statement holds for all $C$ with $C \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0}$? From what you have written it is so far only a necessary condition, right?

Comment: It doesn't strike me as particularly likely, mostly because this seems like an unnatural, (and unmotivated) question.